# PHP - How to iteratively reduce a variable each week at a certain time?

Tags: php

Can anyone offer suggestions on how to reduce a value by a certain amount on a weekly basis, say Sunday at midnight in the local time (neither I nor the server are in the local time zone)?.

For example, the displayed value might be 1000, and I need it to reduce by 100 every week from midnight on each respective Sunday at midnight (so that in week 2 the displayed value is 900, the week after 800 and so on).

Can anyone offer any suggestions on how to go about that?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What happens at the tenth week?

Comment: http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html

Comment: @ Ameenulla0007 -Long before the iteration reduces to zero the page will be deleted so 'bottoming out' isn't an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$amtToReduce = 100;
$todaysDate = new DateTime("now");
$startDate = new DateTime("2016-08-21"); //Sunday's date
$getDiff = $startDate->diff($todaysDate);
$numDays = (int)$getDiff->days; //returns number of days between two dates
$productPrc = $actualPrice = 1000;
if($numDays%7==0) { //condition to allow only sundays
   $toInc = $numDays/7;
   $toReduce = $toInc*$amtToReduce;
   $productPrc = $actualPrice-$toReduce;
   //alter any condition here, to stop incrementing reducing price
}

echo $producPrc; //prints 100 RS less on each incrementing week end
```

Check the above piece of code, hope this could be helpful.

Unable to format my code on mobile, hope someone would edit and format it, surely appreciable.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts ameenulla0007, but I'm not sure if that code works. Using it and amending the trial server date doesn't do anything to the initial value. Of course, this is assuming I'm implementing it right.

Comment: Have your try once, if you face a problem with it. Contact me here, I'll be available. The assumptions are done, because I don't know what exactly you are going to do with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help ameenulla0007 - you gave me enough to go on (the only problem with your code was that it only worked on a Sunday - that's my fault for not explaining it properly (as highlighted by someone downvoting my very first question - tough crowd!)). Here's what I ended up doing:

```
$amtToReduce = 100;
$todaysDate = new DateTime("now");
$startDate = new DateTime("2016-08-21"); 
$getDiff = $startDate->diff($todaysDate);
$numDays = (int)$getDiff->days; 
$productPrc = $actualPrice = 1000;
$discountFactor = floor($numDays/7);
$toReduce = $discountFactor*$amtToReduce;
$productPrc = $actualPrice-$toReduce;
echo $productPrc;
```

After that it worked perfectly. Thanks again - much appreciated!

Comment: That's great! Cool one.. :)